# *& With Respect to Pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

UPDATE: I think I have done well in my exam; thanks for everyone's help and hope you have a nice week(end)!

I am currently revising pointers for my C++ exam and came across an example that I still cannot comprehend.

Consider the following (partial) code:

```cpp
int x = 17; 

int *ptr = &x; 

cout<<*&ptr<<" "<<&ptr<<" "<<ptr<<" "<<*ptr<<endl;
```

I understand that `&ptr` and `ptr` are the same, i.e. that print the address of variable `x`. I also understand that `*ptr` prints out the value inside variable `x`, i.e. 17.

However, I cannot understand the first one, i.e. `*&ptr`. It prints an address, but I do not know to which it points to. I have tried researching it, but I did not find much on it. What does the `*&` combination represent?

Comment: `*&x` and `*&*&x` and so on are basically the same. Dereference a pointer reference. Remember the order in which these operators are evaluated and what effect they have on the type and value. In other words, what type do you think `&ptr` is, and what then is `*&ptr`?

Comment: "I understand that &ptr and ptr are the same" they are not. `ptr` is the address of `x`. `&ptr` is the address of `ptr`

Comment: What do you mean please? Apologies for this as I am not that familiar to C++.

Comment: you should include the output in the question and say specifically which output is unclear

Comment: All variables have address, **even pointer variables**. `&x` is the address of the variable `x` and `&ptr` is the address of the variable `ptr`. The fact that `ptr` is also a pointer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

`ptr` and `&ptr` are **not** the same. `&ptr` is the address of `ptr` (i.e., a pointer to a pointer).

`*` is the dereference operator - it returns the value the pointer points to. So, if you dereference `&ptr`, you're asking for "the value that the address of `ptr` is pointing to", or `ptr` (which, of course, is in turn, the address of `x`).

Comment: So *&ptr would be asking for the address of the address of the value inside x?

Comment: `*&ptr` is asking for the value of `ptr`. Just like `*&x` is asking for the value of `x`.

Comment: One of the problems here is that you are thinking that pointers are something special. You learned how `int` variables work, well in most ways pointer variables work the same.

Comment: Address of an address doesn't make sense. Nor does address of a value. Variables have addresses, but values and addresses do not.

Answer (score 1):

in `*&ptr` expression, operator precedence is the same for `*` and for `&` (but precedence is from right to left). So it just takes address of `ptr` (stack address), but then dereferences it, basically that is equivalent to just `ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

You have (fantasy memory addresses):

```
 variable         value          address

 x                17             0x0001
 ptr == &x        0x0001         0x0002
```

`*` dereferences a pointer. For example `*ptr` uses the value of `ptr` which is `0x0001` and looks what value it find at that address: `17`.

`&` on the other hand is the address-of operator. `&x` is the address of `x`, it is `0x0001`. The address of `x` is `ptr`.

`&*ptr` is just `ptr`.

> I understand that &ptr and ptr are the same ...

No they are not. `ptr` is the address of `x` (`0x0001`). `&ptr` is the address of `ptr` (`0x0002`).

Comment: Thank you all for the explenation(s)!. You were right, &ptr is not equal to ptr. Due to the text being small I did not see that the end part of both outputs were different.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is maybe not so clear from other answers: in an expression like `*&ptr`, the dereference operator `*` does the inverse operation of the "address_of" operator `&`, so that they effectively cancel out when combined, and the result is that `*&ptr` is identical to `ptr`.

A simple way to think about this is to consider the operation of halving a number (i.e. dividing it by 2) and doubling it (multiplying it by 2). Take any number `x`: if you halve it and then double the result, what do you get? You get `x` back, of course, because those two operations cancel out. You are starting from a value, applying a function to it, and then applying its inverse function, so that you end up with the original value.
`&` and `*` work the same way: you have a variable `ptr` with its value, you take the address of that variable with `&`, and then `*` takes that address and gives you the value that is stored there, which is the value of `ptr`.

This means that `*&ptr` is identical to `ptr`, and you can do this `*&` trick it as many times as you want: it would be the same if you wrote `*&*&*&*&*&ptr`. In case you are wondering, all these operators are evaluated from right to left, because that's what the [table of precedence and associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) says (they have the same precedence, 2, and when you have multiple operators with the same precedence you apply them in the order specified by the associativity).